# MySql: Update geometry point

Tags: mysql, sql-update, geospatial, dbeaver

I'm struggling for a seemingly easy and straightforward scenario.
I have a geometry field defined in a table in MySql database:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` char(38) NOT NULL,
  `checkin_location` geometry DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now for a test, I'm just executing this simple statement:

`update mytable set checkin_location = Point(50.8, 4.44)`

I get a green success message which tells me that 1 record has been affected. (I have only 1 record at the moment in the table).

But when I execute `select * from mytable`, the row returns with `checkin_location` field still `NULL`: the update statement seems to have (silently) failed.

I'm new to MySql in general. Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Spacial types must be of the correct type, also when you try to select them look for Spacial indexes

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE geom (Id int
                   ,checkin_location GEOMETRY NULL,
                  g POINT NULL);

INSERT INTO `geom` VALUES (1,NULL, NULL);

UPDATE `geom` set 
checkin_location = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(50.8  4.44)')
, g = POINT(50.8, 4.44) WHERE id = 1;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM `geom`;

| Id  | checkin_location     | g                   |
| --- | -------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | {"x":50.8,"y":4.44}  | {"x":50.8,"y":4.44} |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9by6GKNcQfNE2NTvLywtxR/5)